# Deleting files from a directory using a csv file in python

Tags: python, file, operating-system, glob, pathlib

I am looking to delete files from multiple folders using a .csv file. The csv file contains a list of file names that need to be deleted(example: Box4, 60012-01). How the data is stored is in multiple folder and also had additional extension (example: /tiles_20X_299/Box20/660491-3_mag20_xpos5980_ypos6279.jpg. Is there a way to get these files deleted. Help would be really appreciated.
This is what I have till now but not sure if I'm going the right direction.
[sample of the csv file to delete][1]

````
fin = open('files_to_delete.csv', 'r')
fin.readline()
print(fin)
file_to_delete = set()
while True:
    line = fin.readline().strip()
    #print(line)
    if not line:
        break
    array = line.split(',')
    file_to_delete.add("Box" + array[0] + "/" + array[1])
fin.close()
print(file_to_delete)
#
for path in glob.glob('/home/sshah/Tiles/tiles_20X_299/*'):
    for f in file_to_delete:
        print(f)
        os.chdir(path)
        #print(path)
        if os.path.exists(f):
            print('delete')
            #os.remove(f)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFCxk.png
````

Comment: How is your csv file formatted exactly? Please update your question to include the first couple lines, including the header.

Comment: Just added the csv file @GordonAitchJay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely going in the right direction.

Assuming you're running at least version 3.5 of Python, you can use `glob.iglob()` to recursively iterate over every file in every subdirectory.

I've tweaked your code to make it a bit more pythonic.

Some specific changes:

- Renamed the `file_to_delete` `set` to `files_to_delete` because it contains multiple files and should be plural.
- Used a `with` statement with the *file object*'s *context manager* to avoid worrying about exceptions and explicitly calling `.close()`.
- Looped over `fin` to get each line without explicitly calling `.readline()`.
- Used `os.path.sep` instead of hardcoding `/`.
- Removed both unnecessary `os.chdir(path)` and `os.path.exists(f)` calls.

It works by iterating over every file in every subdirectory (which gives us the full filepath as a `str`), then we iterate over the `files_to_delete` `set` to check if every `file_to_delete` is a substring of the `filepath`. If it is, delete the file, and `break` out of that loop to continue with the next filepath.

If you know there are no other filenames with a similar base, you can uncomment this line: `files_to_delete.remove(file_to_delete)`. For example, if you have a file called:

*/tiles_20X_299/**Box20/660491-3**_mag20_xpos5980_ypos6279.jpg*

but not another one called:

*/tiles_20X_299/**Box20/660491-3**_mag10_xpos2000_ypos4000.jpg*

To be safe, leave it commented out.

```py
import glob, os

files_to_delete = set()

with open('files_to_delete.csv', 'r') as fin:
    fin.readline() # Consume header
    for line in fin:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            files_to_delete.add('Box' + line.replace(',', os.path.sep)) # Assume none of the files contain a comma

print(files_to_delete)

for filepath in glob.iglob(r'/home/sshah/Tiles/tiles_20X_299/**/*', recursive=True):
    for file_to_delete in files_to_delete:
        if file_to_delete in filepath:
            print('Delete:', filepath)
            #os.remove(filepath)
            #files_to_delete.remove(file_to_delete)
            break
```

Comment: Quick note: `glob.iglob` returns "_an iterator which yields the same values as glob() without actually storing them all simultaneously._". Which saves memory. I have no idea why this isn't the default behaviour of `glob` in Python 3.

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks for the help. @GordonAitchJay